# Notation for repeated application of operator

Tags: soft-question, notation, index-notation

Let's say I have a function $f\left(x_{1},\dots,x_{n}\right)$ which
takes $n$ arguments. Now, I want to take the partial derivative:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{3}}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{7}}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{9}}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{12}}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{14}}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{16}}f$$ 
for example (so it is a mixed partial derivative with respect to arguments 3,7,9,12,14, and 16). In this case I can write it and it isn't so bad. But
I am looking for a more compact notation for when I have the indices
in a set $I=\left\{ 3,7,9,12,14,16\right\} $.

I am looking for something
similar to when we take an iterated product or sum and we use $\prod_{i\in I}$
or $\sum_{i\in I}$, so maybe something like $\partial_{i\in I}$?
but I am wondering if this a standard notation or whether there is
some standard notation for this?

Another case in which I want to use such a notation for a repreated
operator is with finite differences. So say I want to take the finite
difference with respect to some arguments of the function, and want
to do it iteratively for some set of indices.

EDIT: To clarify, I am looking for a way to do this for an arbitrary set $I$, which could be much larger than 6 elements.

Comment: $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_I}$ is commonly used.

Comment: I believe the standard solution is to use a multi-index: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-index_notation

Answer (score 1):

You have to be aware that these operators do not necessarily commute (there are conditions on $f$ though that make them commute).

In the face of non-commutativity you can't use an index set as these are not ordered and the order of the factors are important.

Apart from that I haven't seen the use of $\prod$ and $\sum$ in rings, but I suppose there should be little room for misunderstanding. If that's the case the reasonable way to write it would be:

$$\left(\prod_{j=3,7,9,12,14,16}\partial_j\right)f$$

note the parenthesis - you don't want to confuse it with $(\partial_3 f)(\partial_7 f)(\partial_9 f)\cdots$

However if you're looking for a compact notation you also can use:

$$\partial_3\partial_7\partial_9\partial_{12}\partial_{14}f$$

which to me looks a bit more compact (it relies on that the operator itself has a fairly compact notation). You can also in this case use $$f'''''_{3,7,9,12,14}$$

which is even more compact (but it is special for the partial derivative operator).